# Off click of focused div not activating on jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Here is my HTML

```
$html .= "  <td><div class='edit_course' data-id='{$id}' data-type='_title' contenteditable='true'>{$obj->title}</div></td>";
```

Here is my `jQuery`:

```
var selector = 'div[contenteditable="true"]';
// initialize the "save" function
$(selector).focus(function(e) {
    content_holder = $(this);
    content = content_holder.html();

    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var type = $(this).data('type');

    alert( id + type)

    // one click outside the editable area saves the content
    $('body').one('click', function(e) {
        // but not if the content didn't change
        if ($(e.target).is(selector) || content == content_holder.html()) {
            return;
        }

        // Edited out AJAX call
    });
});
```

The problem is, when I click on the `div`, the alert below triggers.  When I click outside of the `div` (after the edit has been made), nothing happens.  Can anyone see what is happening?

First click let's user edit content in div.  The first click outside, should make `ajax` call to save.

**EDIT:**  From recommendation below.

*Here is new code this works perfectly except it calls the DB every time, all I need is a check to do that only if data is different and I think I got it from there.*

**Edit2: Final Code**

```
    var original_value = '';
    $(".edit_course").focus(function(e) {
        original_value = $(this).html();
    });

    // initialize the "save" function
    $(".edit_course").blur(function(e) {
        var content = $(this).html();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var type = $(this).data('type');
        if (content !== original_value) {
            // Ajax edited out
        }
    });
```

Comment: You're not using one() correctly. What you should do is run the AJAX when focus is taken away from the div. Using blur() would probably be your best bet here.

Comment: Hey that was a better, simpler idea.  See code above.  It basically works.

Comment: Cool. I understand why you tried one(), but read the docs on it and you'll see why you were having an issue.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  You can post your recommendation as answer; also, maybe I did it wrong but I was copying this tutorial https://gist.github.com/smottt/2360062

Comment: I don't think you did it wrong, I just thought you'd be better off with blur. The reason for using one() is to keep the user from focusing and unfocusing, causing multiple AJAX calls. If one() isn't handled correctly it can cause other problems as you have seen.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I was using it.  But blur doesn't seem to have that issue so that is even better; final code posted above; marked you correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using one() correctly. What you should do is run the AJAX when focus is taken away from the div. Using blur() would probably be your best bet here.

```
$('body').blur(function(e) {
    // your code here...
});
```